# list of dictionaries to pd dataframe with a single row

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries and I'm trying to create a pd.DataFrame with a single row where the key of the dictionary is a column and the value of the dictionary is its row.

Here is a sample:

```
list_of_dicts = [{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2':'value2'}]
```

Output DataFrame should look like:

```
key1   | key2
value1 | value2
```

I've already tried:

`pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)`, but I get something like this:

```
key 1   | key2
value1  | NaN
NaN     | value2
```

I've already tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for e in list_of_dicts:
    for k, v in e.items():
        df[k] = k
```

But it creates an empty DataFrame with dictionary keys as column but with no value.
Could you help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few possibilities.

Using a dictionary comprehension and [`pd.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({0: {k: v for d in list_of_dicts
                                 for k,v in d.items()}},
                            orient='index')
```

Or with [`ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) (warning if efficiency is important: `ChainMap` adds an overhead):

```
from collections import ChainMap
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({0: dict(ChainMap(*list_of_dicts))},
                            orient='index')
```

Or combined with [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
df = pd.json_normalize(dict(ChainMap(*list_of_dicts)))
```

Or, with [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df = pd.concat(map(pd.Series, list_of_dicts)).to_frame().T
```

Output:

```
     key1    key2
0  value1  value2
```

Answer (score 1):

In your solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for e in list_of_dicts:
    for k, v in e.items():
        df[k] = k
```

Shouldn't the last line be:

```
df[k] = v
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this lines of code:

```
import pandas as pd

list_of_dicts = [{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2':'value2'}]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: v for d in list_of_dicts for k, v in d.items()}, orient='index').T

print(df)
```

**Result:**

```
     key1    key2
0  value1  value2
```